# Node JS Azure function get the response data after post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, azure-functions

I am creating a common Azure function using JavaScript. The function will handle POST calls and POST the values to Another API. The function is working as expected, but i am unable to get the response value after POST method using request in Azure function

```
    module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var request = require("request");  
    var options = {
        url: "",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: req.body,
        headers: {                 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    var responseData;
    var req = await request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
            responseData = body; 
            console.log(responseData); // it works
            resolve(responseData);
        }
    });
});

 
}
```

The same logic works when executed as separate node application in local machine. How to get the response value and pass to the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async/await doesn't do anything. Request module does not return a Promise.

It will better if you remove your redundancy code like

```
    module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var request = require("request");  
    var options = {
        url: "",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: req.body,
        headers: {                 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var responseData;
    request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
            responseData =res.body; 
            console.log(responseData); // it works
            resolve(responseData);
        }
    });
});

 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose for the response. I tired removing the redundancy code but still the response is not sent to the origin. the console.log(responseData) gives the expected result. In azure function context.res = { body:  responseData } outside the promise and request module works but not inside them

Comment: I changed the code again... remove another async... and It is recommended to take the body from the response (res.body). try now

Comment: It worked after removing async and was able to get the response by adding context.res = { body: responseData }  inside request module. Thank you very much for the support